# Sync until async work is done using generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator

English is not my first language. I'll try hard to explain details as I can. I'm really sorry. 
I'm learning  generator. It's really hard method for beginner like me.....
I tried all thing I can but it doesn't work as I expected.

```
function* httpget(par_url, par_port, par_agent) 
    {
        let url = new URL(par_url);
        const settings =
        {
            hostname: url.hostname,
            port: par_port,
            path: url.pathname,
            agent: false,
        }
        var data = "";
        http.get(settings, (res) => {
            res.on('data', (chunk) => {
                data += chunk;
            });
            res.on('end', () => {
                console.log("!done!");
                get.next(data);
            });
        }).on("error", (err) => {
            console.log("Error: " + err.message);
        });
        var result = yield "Hello, there!";
        return result;
    }

var get = httpget("http://localhost/index.html", 80, false);
console.log(get.next());
console.log(get);
```

The scenario is pause until getting contents from given url address, and return its contents, assign contents in "get" variable.

This generator should pause its work and return(or yield, I don't really know but I think it works like return)"Hello, there!"
 So that *console.log(get.next())* will log "Hello, there!".

> data = **yield** "Hello, there!";

and wait until next data comes in

```
res.on('end', () => {
    console.log("!done!");
    get.next(data);
});
```

after data in ***through get.next(data)***, This data should assign to result variable
and return its result value.. which it wasn't.

> console.log(get); //Content of "localhost/index.html"?

My theory is that get.next() this function is work asyncly and It won't wait until data comes through get.next(data).

Or I tried trigger next() twice, but this will assign null in result variable.
I have no idea what is going on. What is problem?

Comment: I can totally see how you'd pick this, but it isn't a good use case for generators, and so it's not a good task to try to learn generators with. `http.get` is an *asynchronous* operation. For the generator to yield a value, it needs synchronous access to that value. (While you could have a generator that yielded `null` when it didn't have any data to return at the time you called it, that would be very awkward to use. To do that, you'd need a queue of available data blocks: The `http.get` callback would add to the end of the queue, and the gen. would try to return from the beginning of it)

Comment: @Yoshika Don't worry. English is not many people's native language around here. Mine is French :) At least you wrote a good question

Comment: @JeremyThille Bonjour! Ca va bien? .....I'm learning french too XD thanks

Comment: @T.J.Crowder queue of available data blocks? What is that?

Comment: @Yosika: Both are general programming terms. In this case, probably queue = array, data block = chunk. But again: This is not a good use case for a generator.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder aha! I see. hmm....Then the promise method would be good choice? I found this method in search, I think it would be great alternatives to generator method.

Comment: No, a promise wouldn't be a good fit either, because a promise is resolved only *once*, and you need to do a notification for each chunk you receive. There's no "pub/sub" built into JavaScript, which is why Node has `EventEmitter` and implements `http.get` that way.

Comment: You *could* have a generator which returned a promise for "the next chunk" each time you called it. :-) Probably flagging "no more chunks" with a null resolution value... That would be complex to implement and a pain to use, but...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder actually I'm really confuse.... because My english skills are not good and programming language skills are too. I could just use external modules but it's my ummh... stubborn? I don't know. I think it would better using external modules. Thanks for the great ideas and I'll try those in advacne as i can!